# Spring Security + AngularJS : Personalize 'UsernameNotFoundException' message

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I've made and AngularJs+Spring Security application and I want to personalize the 'UsernameNotFoundException' message.

I went that far.

My Spring Security code:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase();
        Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneByEmail(lowercaseLogin);
        return userFromDatabase.map(
                user -> {
                        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogin, user
                                .getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
                }).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database"));
    }
```

The exception class:

```
public class UsernameNotFoundException extends AuthenticationException {

    public UsernameNotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
$scope.login = function (event,validForm) {
              Auth.login({
                  username: $scope.username,
                  password: $scope.password,
              }).then(function success(data) {
              [...]
              }, function error(data) {
                console.log(data);              
              });
```

And when the exception is throwed i got this on the console.log:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 400, config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request"}
config: Object
data: Object
headers: (name)
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
__proto__: Object
```

But I can't find the message customized. Any idea?

Comment: What kind of behavior you are expecting for?

Comment: I want to get the Exception message ("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database") to differentiate between exceptions.